# Why exactly does Java not allow numeric conditionals like if(5) { ...} if C does?

Tags: java, c, type-systems

I have these two little programs:

## C

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    if (5) {
        printf("true\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("false\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Java

```java
class type_system {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       if (5) {
           System.out.println("true");
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("false");
       }
   }
}
```

which reports the error message:

```
type_system.java:4: error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
       if (5) {
           ^
1 error
```

## My understanding

So far, I understood this example as a demonstration of the different type systems. C is more weakly typed and allows conversion from int to boolean without errors. Java is more strongly typed and fails, because no implicit conversation is allowed.

Therefore, my question: Where did I misunderstand things?

## What I'm not looking for

My question is not related to bad coding style. I know it's bad, but I'm interested in why C does allow it and Java not. Therefore, I'm interested in the language's type system, specifically its strongness.

Comment: Some C compilers *will warn you.*  It's an error all the same; `=` is assignment, not equivalence, and no sane person would write such code.

Comment: @RobertHarvey look at the java snippets in both questions. It is as if these were taken from the same homework assignment (`x=5`)

Comment: @gnat i think my question is a bit different. In your cited one, it is asked about a conversation from int to string - (which is very common, i think.) But i ask about a conversation from int to boolean, which is a bit different, i think. (Because its **less** natural, imho)

Comment: It's not the same question.  I feel like I'm repeating myself here, but it really needs to be the same *question.*  This is not controversial; it's why you can't close-dupe to an *answer*

Comment: Not a Java expert, but your guess definitely seems to be what the compiler is saying.  Robert Harvey makes the argument that using a conditional like that intentionally is bad form, which is definitely possible.  (I have used it in the past myself, but it usually just looks like a bug when someone first glances at the code.)  Java though is known for its rigidness.

Comment: @Panzercrisis my question is **not** regarding code readability. Of course, this code is awful - but i don't ask for that. I want to understand the type system of both languages, or rather if my code has to do with the strongness of a programming language.

Comment: Mainly my comment is a best-guess answer, which isn't seaworthy enough to be posted as an answer, so I left it as a comment.  The code style is just a side comment, and I wasn't assuming anything about your real code.

Comment: @toogley: What is it about the type system in Java that you specifically want to know?  The type system doesn't allow this *because the language specification forbids it.*  The reasons why C allows it and Java does not have everything to do with what's considered acceptable in both languages.  The resulting behavior of the type systems is *the effect* of that, not the cause.

Comment: @toogley: why do you think you misunderstood something? Reading the text again, I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: Why? Because Java, unlike C, has a proper `boolean` type, and not using it is a sign that you don't understand the language.

Comment: Actually, this is *not* an example of weak typing in C. In the past (C89), C did not even have a boolean type, so all "boolean" operations actually operated on `int` values. A more proper example would be `if (pointer)`.

Comment: Because Java wanted c developers to use exceptions instead of returning non-zero error codes. This was a handy way to remind them that they aren't in c anymore. : )

Comment: @Rufflewind can you move your comment into an answer and elaborate more on your argument?

Comment: @toogley [8bittree](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/348789) has already explained it better than I ever could.

Comment: I downvoted because it doesn't seem like much research was done trying to understand this.

Comment: It seems that the original question asked is a bit different than the edited version (which is why some of the comments and answers seem to be answering a different question).  In its current form, there does not seem to be a question here.  What misunderstanding?  Java is behaving exactly as you think it should be.

Comment: @Rufflewind I'd consider not even introducting a separate type as even weaker typing than allowing an implicit conversion to it. Just like I consider javascript using double to represent integers as a form of weak typing.

Comment: There are many things that makes C different from Java and other languages different from each others.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I don't see the clear question in the original version either.  (I just looked over edit history.)  The original poster provides reasoning that exactly explains the behavior, and then says "Where did I misunderstand things?"  toogley: The answer is: Only in thinking that you are misunderstanding something.  (Or that you weren't understanding the exact right answer that you were saying.)

Answer (score 140, accepted):

## 1. C and Java are different languages

The fact that they behave differently should not be terribly surprising.

## 2. C is not doing any conversion from `int` to `bool`

How could it? C didn't even have a true `bool` type to convert to [until 1999](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type#C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_Objective-C.2C_AWK). C was created in the early 1970s, and `if` was part of it before it was even C, back when it was just a series of modifications to [B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_(programming_language))<sup>1</sup>.

`if` wasn't simply a `NOP` in C for nearly 30 years. It directly acted on numeric values. The verbiage in the C standard ([PDF link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)), even over a decade after the introduction of `bool`s to C, still specifies the behavior of `if` (p 148) and `?:` (p 100) using the terms "unequal to 0" and "equal to 0" rather than the Boolean terms "true" or "false" or something similar.

Conveniently, ...

## 3. ...numbers just happen to be what the processor's instructions operate on.

`JZ` and `JNZ` are your basic x86 assembly instructions for conditional branching. The abbreviations are "**J**ump if **Z**ero" and "**J**ump if **N**ot **Z**ero". The equivalents for the PDP-11, where C originated, are `BEQ` ("**B**ranch if **EQ**ual") and `BNE` ("**B**ranch if **N**ot **E**qual").

These instructions check if the previous operation resulted in a zero or not and jump (or not) accordingly.

## 4. Java has a much higher emphasis on safety than C ever did<sup>2</sup>

And, with safety in mind, they decided that restricting `if` to `boolean`s was worth the cost (both of implementing such a restriction and the resulting opportunity costs).

---

<sup>1.</sup> B doesn't even have types at all. Assembly languages generally don't, either. Yet B and assembly languages manage to handle branching just fine.

<sup>2.</sup> In the words of [Dennis Ritchie](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) when describing the planned modifications to B that became C (emphasis mine):

> ...it seemed that a typing scheme was necessary to cope with characters and byte addressing, and to prepare for the coming floating-point hardware. Other issues, **particularly type safety** and interface checking, **did not seem as important then** as they became later.

Comment: Nice point about boolean expressions in C mapping directly to processor instructions.  I hadn't thought about  that before.

Comment: I think point 4 is misleading as it seems to imply C has some smidgen of safety focus... C will let you do basically anything you want: C assumes you know what you're doing, often to spectacularly disastrous results.

Comment: @TemporalWolf You state that as if C letting you do what you want was bad. The difference in my opinion is that C was written for programmers and a basic competence is expected. Java is written for code monkeys and if you can type you can program in it. Often spectacularly badly but who cares right? I will never forget when a teacher in the introductory java class i was forced to take as a part of my CS minor, pointed out that using recursion to compute the Fibonnaci numbers might be useful because it was "easy to write". That's why we have the software we have.

Comment: @DRF Indeed... why bother learning to program when you can just cut-and-paste code all day until that pesky compiler stops complaining :-)

Comment: @DRF One of my professors for a C networking class said "C is like a box of hand grenades with all the pins pulled out." You've got a lot of power, but it's essentially guaranteed to blow up in your face. In the gross majority of cases, it's not worth the hassle, and you'll be far more productive with a higher-level language. Have I transcoded Python into hacky C bit-twiddling to get a 6 order of magnitude increase in speed? Yes, yes I have. But that is the exception, not the rule. I can accomplish in a day in Python what would take me two weeks in C... and I'm a decent C programmer.

Comment: It should be emphasized that this is not about a special rule regarding `if` statements. It applies ts all contexts where a `boolean` value is required, `if`, `while`, the second argument to `for`, or `assert` statements as well as the `…? …: …` expression.

Comment: "numbers just happen to be what the processor's instructions operate on" - and then you go on to show the opposite. `BEQ` and `BNE` don't work on a number, they work on the `Z` bit of the flag register. That is _not_ a number. `x86` is the same.

Comment: wanted to upvote, but noticed that you have *42* upvotes, so will leave it as it is :-P

Comment: Btw, I think Pascal also had a boolean type and required a boolean in an `if` statement. Just so that no-one thinks that this kind of thing is particularly new.

Comment: @TemporalWolf But if you are an explosives expert and are handed the box of hand grenades, chances are that you will survive. Simply because you know what can go wrong. Likewise, good C programmers have developed habits that avoid the dangerous parts of their language. They know you must never overrun a buffer, so they code in a way to ensure that no overrun ever happens. Sadly, they are the minority of C programmers. Nevertheless, I totally agree that there is a lot of stuff that can be written much faster in python than in C.

Comment: @TemporalWolf I added a footnote to clarify that C was not designed with safety in mind.

Comment: @DRF Given the prevalence of buffer overflow exploits in mainstream software developed by top name companies, apparently even programmers with basic competence can't be trusted not to shoot off their feet.

Comment: Although I have no reason to think it factored directly into Java's design, I observe that Java's choice causes a fairly common C mistake to be a compile time error in Java.  In C, `if (x = y)` and similar constructs are perfectly valid when `x` and `y` are integer variables, but they mean something very different from `if (x == y)`.  Usually (but not always), a programmer who writes the former means the latter.

Comment: @DRF Just look at what a skilled C programmer can do and what a skilled C# or java programmer can do in the same time-frame. C#, Java and similar languages are _more productive_ because they give you less guns to shoot yourself in the foot.  I never had to waste time hunting for a memory leak on a C# program.

Comment: @DRF Nowadays C# and Java, and other similar languages, are absurdly powerful. You need skill to tap in that power, however - things like complex lambda expressions, task scheduling and reflection aren't things that code monkeys could do easily.

Comment: @tsar I'm not claiming C is is the most efficient language for writing code in a given time frame. I understand why Java and C# are the languages of choice even for good programmers. I just can't help feeling a little sad that in the 60's they used computers with less computational power than the worst smartphone I can find in my company to send people to the moon, and today we are happy if such computers can reliably reproduce pictures of gems falling without something breaking.

Comment: @DRF Sorry if I became a little acid, but slapping the term "code monkey" for programmers that pick C# or Java over older languages wasn't really nice. Keep in mind that those languages are far deeper than they appear to be.

Comment: @TSar Absolutely no problem. I was being a jerk partly on purpose. Sure you get great C# programmers and Java programmers. I manage an IT company. I know the time constrains people work under and I understand the choices they make. Hell, I force them to make those choices. I'm just bitter that the current climate forces (most) everyone to churn out code fast rather than well.

Comment: @DRF So we both are on the same boat. The thing about most programmers being shitty nowadays isn't really about the language, however - it is about the expectations of the clients - quick software for a cheap price. This bothers me to no end, too.

Comment: @DRF It turns out getting pictures of gems falling is actually really hard, and I'm not being sarcastic. The level of graphics capabilities in modern smartphones far outpaces anything that could be done in 1969. And the example of getting to the moon is so trite - it's a very specific example, and there are a lot more factors at play here than just "programmers in the 60 were better".

Comment: @DRF C doesn't "let you do what you want"; it lets you do what you *say*.  There is a **vast** difference between these two, as anyone who's ever had to debug code knows all too well!

Comment: @cmaster given the prevalence of buffer overflow exploits even in security-focused systems carefully built and audited by very competent developers, apparently there are zero people in this planet that can be trusted not to shoot off their feet. *Everybody* gets in an overflow sometimes, and there's no practical way in C to ensure that no overrun *ever* happens - or, at least, the core developers of OpenSSL, BSD and Linux kernels etc are unaware of those ways.

Comment: @cmaster There is a minority of programmers that can program _at all_. Doesn't matter the language - most people that dabble nowadays in software development aren't a good fit for it. Not because they are dumb or anything like that. Much like teaching, advanced maths or art, you _need_ a specific mindset to be able to be a good developer.

Comment: @Peteris And that is actually still in perfect accordance of the explosive-expert analogy: Any explosive expert has a non-zero chance to make a mistake and be blown to pieces on each job. I guess, the difference is, that we programmers handle a lot more hand grenades each week than an explosive expert handles in their lifetime. And sometimes we do fail. Some more than others, some less, but all fail eventually. Nevertheless, a good C programmer does stand quite a good chance to handle a *lot* of hand grenades in between the explosions... (Small comfort, is it?)

Comment: @TSar  Amen to that :-)

Comment: @Peteris While true I think it overstates the case a bit. In many cases a memory safety in kernels is... problematic since you program DMA and manipulate page tables directly. At the end of the day "[y]ou can't just place a LISP book on top of an x86 chip and hope the hardware learns about lambda calculus by osmosis" - not getting into problems of side-channel attacks. For vast majority of such problems there is no good replacement other than _maybe_ C++ and, in future, Rust.

Comment: Actually, BCPL had `if` before there was even a `B`. Source: I was on the [BravoX Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bravo_\(software\)) in 1978 and it was written in BCPL.

Comment: @JohnBollinger If you want to talk about safety, specifically regarding that construct, I must say that Java is both too restrictive (It's perfectly clear what `if (pointer)` or `if (!pointer)` *should* mean) and too lax (`if (a = b)` is probably an error even if both are boolean). What they should have done, and what any decent c linter or compiler warns against, is ban bare assignment where a truth-value is expected, extra-parentheses suppressing that.

Answer (score 15):

[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.8.4.1 The `if` statement**
> **Constraints**
> 1    The controlling expression of an `if` statement shall have scalar type.
> **Semantics**
> 2    In both forms, the first substatement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.
> In the `else` form, the second substatement is executed if the expression compares equal to 0. If the first substatement is reached via a label, the second substatement is not
> executed.
> 3    An `else` is associated with the lexically nearest preceding if that is allowed by the
> syntax.

Note that this clause specifies only that the controlling expression shall have a scalar type (`char`/`short`/`int`/`long`/etc.), not specifically a Boolean type.  A branch is executed if the controlling expression has a non-zero value.

Compare that with

[Java SE 8 Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/jls8.pdf)

> **14.9 The `if` Statement**
> The `if` statement allows conditional execution of a statement or a conditional
> choice of two statements, executing one or the other but not both.
>
> ```
>     IfThenStatement:
>         if ( Expression ) Statement
>
>     IfThenElseStatement:
>         if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else Statement
>
>     IfThenElseStatementNoShortIf:
>         if ( Expression ) StatementNoShortIf else StatementNoShortIf
> ```
>
> The *Expression* must have type `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error
> occurs.

Java, OTOH, *specifically requires* that the controlling expression in an `if` statement have a Boolean type.

So, it's not about weak vs. strong typing, it's about what each respective language definition specifies as a valid control expression.

**Edit**

As for *why* the languages are different in this particular respect, several points:

1. C was derived from B, which was a "typeless" language - basically, everything was a 32- to 36-bit word (depending on the hardware), and all arithmetic operations were integer operations.  C's type system was bolted on a bit at a time, such that...
2. C didn't have a distinct Boolean type until the 1999 version of the language.  C simply followed the B convention of using zero to represent `false` and non-zero to represent `true`.
3. Java post-dates C by a good couple of decades, and was designed specifically to address some of C's and C++'s shortcomings.  No doubt tightening the restriction on what may be a control expression in an `if` statement was part of that.
4. There's no reason to expect *any* two programming languages to do things the same way.  Even languages as closely related as C and C++ diverge in some interesting ways, such that you can have legal C programs that are not legal C++ programs, or are legal C++ programs but with different semantics, etc.

Comment: Too sad, i can't mark two answers as "accepted"..

Comment: Yes, this is a good restatement of the question.  But the question asked _why_ there's this difference between the two languages.  You haven't addressed this at all.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem: The question was why C allowed conversion from `int` to `boolean` while Java didn't.  The answer is that there's no such conversion in C.  The languages are different because they are different languages.

Comment: Yes, "it's not about weak vs. strong typing". Just look at auto-boxing and auto-unboxing. If C had those, it couldn't allow any scalar type either.

Answer (score 5):

Many of the answers seem to be targeting the embedded assignment expression that is within the conditional expression.  (While that is a known kind of potential pitfall, it is not the source of the Java error message in this case.)

Possibly this is because the OP did not publish the actual error message, and, the `^` caret points directly to the `=` of the assignment operator.

However the compiler is pointing to the `=` because it is the operator that produces the final value (and hence the final type) of the expression that the conditional sees.

It is complaining about testing a non-boolean value, with the following kind of error:

> error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean

Testing integers, while sometimes convenient, is considered a potential pitfall that the Java designers choose to avoid.  After all, *Java has a **true boolean data type**, which C does **not** (it has no boolean type)*.

This also applies to C's testing pointers for null/non-null via `if (p) ...` and `if (!p) ...`, which Java similarly does not allow instead requiring an explicit comparison operator to obtain the required boolean.

Comment: C _does_ have a boolean type. But that's newer than the `if` statement.

Comment: @MSalters C's bool is still an integer under covers, hence you can do `bool b = ...; int v = 5 + b;`. This is different to languages with a full boolean type which cannot be used in arithmetic.

Comment: C's boolean is just a really small integer.  "true" and "false" could easily be defined with macros or whatever.

Comment: @Jules: You're just pointing out that C has weak type-safety. Just because  a boolean type _converts_ to an integer value doesn't mean it _is_ an integer type. By your logic, integer types would be floating-point types since `int v = 5; float f = 2.0 + v;` is legal in C.

Comment: @MSalters actually `_Bool` is one of the _standard unsigned integer types_ as defined by the Standard (see 6.2.5/6).

Comment: @Ruslan: "Because the Standard says so" is indeed the correct reason.

Answer (score 2):

> incompatible types: int cannot be converted to boolean
>
> I'm interested in why C does allow it and java not. Therefore, I'm interested in the language's type system, specifically its strongness.

There are two parts to your question:

#### Why does Java not convert `int` to `boolean`?

This boils down to Java being intended to be as explicit as possible. It is very static, very "in your face" with its type system. Things that are automatically type-cast in other languages are not so, in Java. You have to write `int a=(int)0.5` as well. Converting `float` to `int` would lose information; same as converting `int` to `boolean` and would thus be error-prone. Also, they would have had to specify a lot of combinations. Sure, these things seem to be obvious, but they intended to err on the side of caution.

Oh, and compared to other languages, Java was *hugely* exact in its specification, as the bytecode was not just an internal implementation detail. They would have to specified any and all interactions, precisely. Huge undertaking.

#### Why does `if` not accept other types than `boolean`?

`if` could perfectly well be defined as to allow other types than `boolean`. It could have a definition that says the following are equivalent:

- `true`
- `int != 0`
- `String` with `.length>0`
- Any other object reference that is non-`null` (and not a `Boolean` with value `false`).
- Or even: any other object reference that is non-`null` and whose method `Object.check_if` (invented by me just for this occasion) returns `true`.

They didn't; there was no real need to, and they wanted to have it as robust, static, transparent, easy to read etc. as possible. No implicit features. Also, the implementation would be pretty complex, I'm sure, having to test each value for all possible cases, so performance just may have played a small factor as well (Java used to be sloooow on the computers of that day; remember there was no JIT compilers with the first releases, at least not on the computers I used then).

#### Deeper reason

A deeper reason could well be the fact that Java has its primitive types, hence its type system is torn between objects and primitives. Maybe, if they had avoided those, things would have turned out another way. With the rules given in the previous section, they would have to define the truthiness of *every single primitive* explicitely (since the primitives don't share a super class, and there is no well defined `null` for primitives). This would turn into a nightmare, quickly.

#### Outlook

Well, and in the end, maybe it's just a preference of the language designers. Each language seems to spin their own way there...

For example, Ruby has no primitive types. Everything, literally everything, is an object. They have a very easy time making sure that every object has a certain method.

Ruby does look for truthiness on all types of objects you can throw at it. Interestingly enough, it still has no `boolean` type (because it has no primitives), *and* it has no `Boolean` class either. If you ask what class the value `true` has (handily available with `true.class`), you get `TrueClass`. That class actually does have methods, namely the 4 operators for booleans (`| & ^ ==`). Here, `if` considers its value falsey if and only if it is either `false` or `nil` (the `null` of Ruby). Everything else is true. So, `0` or `""` are both true.

It would have been trivial for them to create a method `Object#truthy?` which could be implemented for any class and return an individual truthiness. For example, `String#truthy?` could have been implemented to be true for non-empty strings, or whatnot. They didn't, even though Ruby is the antithesis of Java in most departments (dynamic duck-typing with mixin, re-opening classes and all that).

Which might be surprising to a Perl programmer who is used to `$value <> 0 || length($value)>0 || defined($value)` being the truthiness. And so on.

Enter SQL with its convention that `null` inside any expression automatically makes it false, no matter what. So `(null==null) = false`. In Ruby, `(nil==nil) = true`. Happy times.

Comment: Actually, `((int)3) * ((float)2.5)` is quite well-defined in Java (it is `7.5f`).

Comment: You're right, @PaŭloEbermann, I have deleted that example.

Comment: Woah there... would appreciate comments from the downvoters and the one who voted to actually delete the answer.

Comment: Actually conversion from `int` to `float` also loses information in general. Does Java also forbid such implicit cast?

Comment: @Ruslan no (same for long → double) – I guess the idea is that the potential information loss there is only in the least significant places, and only happens in cases which are deemed not so important (quite large integer values).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other fine answers, I'd like to talk about the consistency between languages.

When we think of a mathematically pure if-statement, we understand that the condition can be either true or false, no other value. Every major programming language respects this mathematical ideal; if you give a Boolean true/false value to an if-statement, then you can expect to see consistent, intuitive behavior all the time.

So far so good. This is what Java implements, and only what Java implements.

Other languages try to bring conveniences for non-Boolean values. For example:

- Suppose `n` is an integer. Now define `if (n)` to be shorthand for `if (n != 0)`.
- Suppose `x` is a floating-point number. Now define `if (x)` to be shorthand for `if (x != 0 && !isNaN(x))`.
- Suppose `p` is a pointer type. Now define `if (p)` to be shorthand for `if (p != null)`.
- Suppose `s` is a string type. Now define `if (s)` to be `if (s != null && s != "")`.
- Suppose `a` is an array type. Now define `if (a)` to be `if (a != null && a.length > 0)`.

This idea of providing shorthand if-tests seems good on the surface... until you run into differences in designs and opinions:

- `if (0)` is treated as false in C, Python, JavaScript; but treated as true in Ruby.
- `if ([])` is treated as false in Python but true in JavaScript.

Each language has its own good reasons for treating expressions one way or another. (For example, the only falsy values in Ruby are `false` and `nil`, hence `0` is truthy.)

Java adopted an explicit design to force you to supply a Boolean value to an if-statement. If you hastily translated code from C/Ruby/Python to Java, you cannot leave any lax if-tests unchanged; you need to write out the condition explicitly in Java. Taking a moment to pause and think can save you from sloppy mistakes.

Comment: Do you know that `x != 0` is the same as `x != 0 && !isNaN(x)`? Also, it's normally `s != null` for pointers, but something else for non-pointers.

Comment: @Deduplicator in which language is that the same?

Comment: Using IEEE754, NaN ≠ 0. NaN ≠ anything at all. So if (x) would execute, and if (! x) would execute as well...

Answer (score 0):

Well, every scalar type in C, pointer, boolean (since C99), number (floating-point or not) and enumeration (due to direct mapping to numbers) has a "natural" falsey value, so that's good enough for any conditional expression.

Java has those too (even if Java pointers are called references and are heavily restricted), but it introduced auto-boxing in Java 5.0 which muddles the waters unacceptably. Also, Java-programmers exhort the intrinsic value of typing more.

The one error which spawned the debate whether restricting conditional expressions to boolean type is the typo of writing an assignment where a comparison was intended, which is *not* addressed by restricting the conditional expressions type *at all*, but by disallowing use of a naked assignment-expression for its value.

Any modern C or C++ compiler handles that easily, giving a warning or error for such questionable constructs if asked.
For those cases where it is exactly what was intended, adding parentheses helps.

To summarize, restricting to boolean (and the boxed equivalent in Java) looks like a failed attempt to make a class of typos caused by choosing `=` for assignment compile-errors.

Comment: Using `==` with boolean operands, of which the first one is a variable (which then could by typo'ed to `=`) inside an `if` happens much less often than with other types, I would say, so it is only a semi-failed attempt.

Comment: Having 0.0 -> false and any value other than 0.0 -> true doesn't look "natural" to me at all.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Partial result with unfortunate side-effets, while there is an easy way to achieve the aim without side-effects, is a clear failure in my book.

Comment: You're missing the other reasons. What about the truthy value of `""`, `(Object) ""`, `0.0`, `-0.0`, `NaN`, empty arrays, and `Boolean.FALSE`? Especially the last one is funny, as it's non-null pointer (true) which unboxes to false. +++ I also hate writing `if (o != null)`, but saving me a few chars every day and letting me to spend half a day debugging my "clever" expression is no good deal. That said, I'd love to see some middle way for Java: More generous rules but leaving no ambiguity at all.

Comment: @maaartinus: As I said, the introduction of auto-unboxing in Java 5.0 meant if they assigned a truth-value corresponging to null-ness to pointers, they would have quite a problem. But that's a problem with auto-(un-)boxing, not anything else. A language without auto-(un-)boxing like C is happily free of that.

Comment: Sure, but C has no objects, so it needs no (auto-)(un-)boxing or whatever.  C doesn't even have arrays (as something to be passed as an argument), so it doesn't have the empty array problem either. C++ uses templates, so it needs no boxing either. +++ I'm afraid that boxing is currently important in Java (this may change when value types come in) and I agree that it's incompatible with the "truthy value for everybody" idea. I guess, leaving it out was therefore a good decision.

Answer (score -1):

> My question is not related to bad coding style. I know its bad, but i'm intersted in why C does allow it and java not.

Two of the design goals of Java were:

1. **Allow the developer to focus on the business problem.**  Make things simpler and less error-prone, e.g. garbage collection so developers don't need to focus on memory leaks.
2. **Portable** between platforms, e.g. run on any computer with any CPU.

Use of assignment as an expression was known to cause a lot of bugs due to typos, so under goal #1 above, it is not allowed the way you are trying to use it.

Also, inferring that any nonzero value = true and any zero value = false is not necessarily portable (yes, believe it or not, [some systems treat 0 as true and 1 as false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104225/has-true-always-had-a-non-zero-value)), so under goal #2 above, is not allowed implicitly.  You can still cast explicitly of course.

Comment: Unless it's been added in Java 8, there is no explicit cast between numeric types and Booleans. To convert a numeric value to a Boolean you have to use a comparison operator; to convert a Boolean value to a numeric one you typically use the ternary operator.

Comment: You could make a case for disallowing use of an assignment for its value due to those typos. But considering how often you see == true and  == false in Java, obviously limiting the controlling expression to (optionally boxed) boolean type doesn't help that much.

Comment: Java would trivially ensure portability w.r.t. to "some systems treat 0 as true and 1 as false" as it's Java's zero and Java's false. It really doesn't matter what the OS thinks about it.

Answer (score -1):

As an example what other languages do: Swift requires an expression of a type that supports the "BooleanType" protocol, which means it must have a "boolValue" method. The "bool" type obviously supports this protocol and you can create your own types supporting it. Integer types don't support this protocol.

In older versions of the language optional types supported "BooleanType" so you could write "if x" instead of "if x != nil". Which made using an "Optional bool" very confusing. An optional bool has values nil, false or true and "if b" would be not executed if b was nil and executed if b was true or false. This is not allowed anymore.

And there seems to be one guy who real dislikes opening your horizons...